# Error in adding UIPageViewController as a child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>
> -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Here is my code:

```
UIViewController *p1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
NSLog(@" p1    %@",p1);
UIViewController *p2 = [storyboard
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
UIViewController *p3 = [storyboard
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
UIViewController *p4 = [storyboard
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fourth"];

_Array = @[p1,p2,p3,p4];

NSLog(@"%@",_Array);

self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

[[self.pageViewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];

[_pageViewController setViewControllers:@[p1]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];

[self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: What is the error? You might find it helpful to read [Ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Ok you should edit that into your question and also include what you are doing and what you are expecting to happen

Comment: I have done that .Please help me if you know the solution.

Comment: I am not an objective-c developer so I probably can't answer, but I can help make your question good so that others can answer easily. Are you able to add which line is generating the error?

Comment: This is the line  which is generating an Error   :[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];

Comment: You should check the _pageViewController.view. According to terminal log, there is nil. Put break point  before [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController]; and check _pageViewController.view.

Comment: im sorry ,i'm new to IOS. can you suggest me why _pageViewController is nil?

Comment: check your identifier in the storyboard. probably its wrong so he cannot instantiate the pageViewController

Comment: Thank you so much!! got output...;)